# How could I reshape a DF of n columns into a unified DF with 3 columns where's n is always a multiple of 3?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to reshape my pandas DataFrame of `n` columns (which are always multiples of 3) into a combined DF with 3 columns.
Atm I'm using a dirty method of splitting the original DF into individual DFs and them merging it all together.
In code is looks something like this, where the numbers represent the columns (0-14):

```
DF =[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]]
DF1 = DF[[0,1,2]]
DF2 = DF[[3,4,5]]

...
```

then

```
merged_df = pd.concat([DF1, DF2, ..., DFn])
```

My questions is, what would be a better way to handle a DF with n columns?

Comment: look at `np.reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to [@Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) for pointing me in the right direction. Thank you!

managed to come up with the following solution.

```
df['column1'].str.split(',', expand=True)
df = df.to_numpy()
num = df.shape
num = int((num[0]*num[1])/3)
```